# Java 8: Class to AnnotatedType

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8, `Class` appears to have gained methods to get an `AnnotatedType` view of its superclasses and its superinterfaces.

How can you convert a `Class` to its *own* `AnnotatedType`?  Does that question even make sense?

From what I can tell, an `AnnotatedType` has-a `Type`, not is-a `Type`.  It's an `AnnotatedElement`, though; it's all very messy.

I have searched through the Javadocs to no avail, so far.

Comment: I think I've figured out that it's nonsensical: _usages_ of a type can be annotated, but the type itself can't be.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what an annotated use of a type is and how it applies to `getAnnotatedSuperclass()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I finally got an acceptable understanding of the `AnnotatedType` interface. Here's a working Java 8 example to illustrate one of its uses

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?> fooClass = Foo.class;
    AnnotatedType type = fooClass.getAnnotatedSuperclass();
    System.out.println(type);
    System.out.println(Bar.class == type.getType());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(type.getAnnotations()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(type.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
}

public static class Bar {
}

public static class Foo extends @Custom Bar {
}

// So that annotation metadata is available at run time
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
// TYPE_USE being the important one
@Target(value = {ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE,
        METHOD, PACKAGE, PARAMETER, TYPE, TYPE_PARAMETER, TYPE_USE}) 
public @interface Custom {
}
```

This prints

```
sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl@1d44bcfa
true
[@com.testing.Test$Custom()]
[@com.testing.Test$Custom()]
```

The [`AnnotatedType`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedType.html) interface states

> `AnnotatedType` represents the **potentially** annotated use of a type in
>   the program currently running in this VM.

and [`Class#getAnnotatedSuperclass()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotatedSuperclass--) javadoc states

> Returns an `AnnotatedType` object that represents the use of a type to
>   specify the superclass of the entity represented by this `Class` object.

I've made *potentially* bold in the `AnnotatedType` javadoc because it makes it clear that the type usage doesn't have to be annotated. If you had

```
public static class Bar {}
...
Bar.class.getAnnotatedSuperclass(); // returns Class instance for java.lang.Object
```

This is a use case that wasn't possible in Java 7 and lower because you could not annotate type usages ([see some examples here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/ec-public/materials/2012-01-1011/jsr308-201201.pdf)). In Java 8, however, you can do

```
public static class Foo extends @Custom Bar {
```

where the type `Bar` is used as a super class and its usage is annotated with `@Custom`. It is therefore an `AnnotatedType`. Therefore, `Foo.class.getAnnotatedSuperClass()` will return an `AnnotatedType` instance for that usage.

> How can you convert a `Class` to its own `AnnotatedType`? Does that
>   question even make sense?

The question doesn't make sense. This is because a `Class` object holds self-contained metadata about a class. By self-contained, I mean everything that can be deduced from the class' `.class` file (or actual declaration). You cannot deduce any usages of the type anywhere else and therefore it cannot be converted to any `AnnotatedType` for itself.

You can have

```
public static class Foo extends @Custom Bar {}

public static class Zoom extends @Custom Bar {}

public static class Doing extends @Custom Bar {}
```

There is an `AnnotatedType` instance for each of the above uses of `Bar`, but which one would you chose to *convert a [Bar] `Class` to its own `AnnotatedType`*?

Comment: Gack! You beat me to posting an example of this. +1 anyway. :-)

Comment: Note that @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) is significant as well. If it's omitted, the example won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example showing the usage of `getAnnotatedSuperclass()`:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface First { }

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Second { }

    class A { }

    class B extends @First @Second A { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Annotation[] anns = B.class.getAnnotatedSuperclass().getAnnotations();
        System.out.printf("There are %d annotations on B's use of its superclass.%n", anns.length);
        for (Annotation a : anns)
            System.out.println(a.annotationType().getName());
    }
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
There are 2 annotations on B's use of its superclass.
AnnotationTest$First
AnnotationTest$Second
```

Note the distinction of annotations occurring at the **use** of B's superclass (namely A) as opposed to the **declaration** of A itself.